# Emulate normally closed relay with 2 normally open relays

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, car, electronics

Good afternoon, I have recently ordered a normally closed relay to fix on my car's daylight-running lights. When the main lights come on the DLR should switch-off. Unfortunately amazon has delivered instead of a normally closed 2 normally open relays (!!?). Is there a clever way to emulate the normally closed relays functionality with two normally open relays?
Thanks in advance.

regards
perry

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just return the items sent in error and get Amazon to send the correct part?

Comment: @Eric: Where's the fun in that?

Comment: yes, it would be easier. unfortunately i am stuck with the parts in a remote place for now. so making the best out of it, and actually is fun to find a way to get it going still. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a chance. This might work as a temporary solution.

[image]

*Figure 1. Switching DLRs off with an NO when headlights are on.*

How it works:

- When the ignition is on and the headlights are off the headlamps will provide a low enough resistance to allow the RLY to pick up. The normally open (NC) contact will close and the DLRs will turn on.
- When the headlamps are on there will be 12 V on both sides of the relay so no current will flow and the relay will drop out switching off the DLRs.

[image]

*Figure 2. Modification to detect both dip and high beam status.

- The DLRs will turn on only if both DIP and HIGH are off.

Note that in both circuits I've powered the relay from a line switched by the ignition. This will avoid draining the battery when the ignition is turned off.

Comment: this sounds like a good proposal. i will try to find an ignition plus in the fuse box in the engine compartment and take it from there.

Comment: thanks for taking the effort. i tried to upvote your post, but i have not enough reputation, as i asked what seemed like not so good questions in another threat.

Comment: Let us know how you get on.